# While loop and executing commandsds in remote machine

Tags: while-loop, ansible

I have the following commands which needs to be included in Ansible.

How can I incorporate these commands in Ansible module?

```
while sudo fuser /var/lib/dpkg/lock >/dev/null 2>&1 ; do
    sleep 1
done
while sudo fuser /var/lib/apt/lists/lock >/dev/null 2>&1 ; do
    sleep 1
done
if [ -f /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log ]; then
  while sudo fuser /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log >/dev/null 2>&1 ; do
    sleep 1
  done
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use a chunk of code in the `shell` module using the [block style indicator for literal of YAML](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2795688): `|`.

Just mind that the code should be further indented than the `shell` task.

```yaml
- shell: |
    while sudo fuser /var/lib/dpkg/lock >/dev/null 2>&1 ; do
      sleep 1
    done
    while sudo fuser /var/lib/apt/lists/lock >/dev/null 2>&1 ; do
        sleep 1
    done
    if [ -f /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log ]; then
      while sudo fuser /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log >/dev/null 2>&1 ; do
        sleep 1
      done
    fi
```

You could also refactor a little bit using a [`loop`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html):

```yaml
- shell: |
    if [ -f {{ item }}]; then
      while sudo fuser {{ item }} >/dev/null 2>&1 ; do
        sleep 1
      done
    fi
  loop:
    - /var/lib/dpkg/lock
    - /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
    - /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log
```